# Filter columns with DataTables Buttons based on attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a custom button above my DataTables. When pressed I want it to filter the first column on a attribute value since this column cells only contain images (flags of countries/regions).

My table looks like this:

```
<table id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Region</th>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-order="United States"><img src="img/region_usa.png"></td>
            <td>George</td>
            <td>Washington</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-order="Europe"><img src="img/region_eur.png"></td>
            <td>Michael</td>
            <td>Ferguson</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-order="Japan"><img src="img/region_jap.png"></td>
            <td>Yuka</td>
            <td>Sakamari</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my initilization:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "Filter: USA",
            action: function(e, dt, node, config){
                dt.column(0).search("United States").draw();
            }
        }
    ]
})
```

However this doesn't do anything unfortunately. What am I doing wrong?

I used [Buttons collection](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/collections.html), [Buttons.action](https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.buttons.action) and [column.search()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search()) as reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember import `datatTables.buttons.js`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
```

change your attr `data-order` by `data-search` (check HTML5 attr https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html)

```
...
<td data-search="United States"><img src="img/region_usa.png"></td>
...
```

and indicate the `dom`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#example').DataTable({
   dom: 'Bfrtip',
   buttons: [
    {
        text: "Filter: United States",
        action: function(e, dt, node, config){
            dt.column(0).search("United States").draw();
        }
    }
    ]
})

});
```

**Result :** https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/63/

Comment: Completely missed the data-search attribute. Thanks a lot!